# AngularJS - Child sub arrays not being returned from API call

Tags: angularjs

I am using a Breeze Web Api controller to retrieve menu items:

```
    public IQueryable<MenuItem> MenuItems()
    {
        var result = _repository.MenuItems.OrderBy(c => c.FK_DbModuleId).ThenBy(d => d.OrderNum);
        return result;
    }
```

It is being called from an angular factory service:

```
app.factory('menuItems', function ($http) {
    return {
        all: function () {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:9669/api/breeze/menuitems',
                method: 'GET'
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I have menu items that have submenu items:

[image]

They are being returned from the API controller properly:

[image]

But angular is ignoring the submenu items:

[image]

I tried adding "isArray:true" to http call, no success.

Any suggestions on how to get the child submenus/sub arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the data is in the parents SubMenus array